# Simple jQuery Checkbox Code for Row Select

Tags: jquery

This code is meant to do the simple task of:

a) Checking the checkbox that exists in the table's `<tr>` row.

b) Adding the "selected" class to the `<tr>` row.

While it does B without problem, I cannot get it to do A.  I have tried every type of jQuery selector including input[name='checked_136'], 'input.action_items', etc. and I just can't get it to mark it as checked.  I've also tried used thing attr('checked',true) to check it but that doesn't make a difference.

Does anyone have some insight?

```
$('table.dataset tbody tr').click(function () {
    var this_row = $(this);
    var checkbox = $(this).children('input.action_items');

    if (checkbox) {
        this_row.children(':checkbox').trigger('click');
        this_row.addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: Just checking, have you only got 1 checkbox in that row?

Comment: Yep it's just the one checkbox.  The row is either checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

Using `.children()` will only get the immediate children (td's, in this case), so it's probably not finding the checkbox.

Try switching it to .`find()`:

```
$('table.dataset tbody tr').click(function () {
    var this_row = $(this);
    var checkbox = this_row.find('input.action_items');

    if (checkbox.length > 0) {
        checkbox.attr('checked', true);
        this_row.addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it the other way around - trigger the event on click of the checkbox instead:

```
$('table.dataset tbody tr :checkbox').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('selected');
});
```

This way, you won't have to trigger the `click` event. Also, don't forget to wrap this in `$(function() { ... });` and use `.live('click', ...)` instead of `.click(...)` if you're fetching the table with AJAX.

**Update:**
Since the original answer was authored, `.live()` has been [deprectated](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and replaced by [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).